# Error when using AsmJit within a Qt GUI Application

Tags: qt, asmjit

*OS: Windows 10*

*IDE: Visual Studio 2015*

I need to use the AsmJit library (https://github.com/asmjit/asmjit) inside my Qt GUI Application. But is is somehow incompatible. When certain headers are included from QT (QWidget etc.), things start to break.

Most errors originate from this line:

```
ASMJIT_INLINE Error emit(uint32_t code, const Operand& o0, const Operand& o1, const Operand& o2, const Operand& o3) {
    return _emit(code, o0, o1, o2, o3);
  }
```

Where `ASMJIT_INLINE` is defined as `__forceinline`.

When I compile it in VS2015, it is giving the following error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2086   'asmjit::Error asmjit::Assembler::Operand': redefinition    Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  472 
Error   C2334   unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body  Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  472 
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  466 
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  468 
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  470 
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  481 
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  483 
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  485 
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  487 
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  489 
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  491 
Error   C2062   type 'int' unexpected   Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  477 
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing '>' before identifier 'uint64_t'  Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  248 
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing '>' before identifier 'uint32_t'  Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  242 
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing '>' before identifier 'uint32_t'  Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  260 
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '&'    Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  466 
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '&'    Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  468 
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '&'    Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  470 
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '&'    Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  472 
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '&'    Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  481 
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '&'    Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  483 
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '&'    Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  485 
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '&'    Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  487 
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '&'    Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  489 
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '&'    Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  491 
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ',' before '&'    Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  494 
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'code'  Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  464 
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'code'  Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  466 
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'code'  Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  468 
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'code'  Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  470 
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'code'  Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  472 
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'code'  Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  477 
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'code'  Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  479 
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'code'  Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  481 
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'code'  Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  483 
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'code'  Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  485 
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'code'  Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  487 
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'code'  Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  489 
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'code'  Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  491 
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'uint64_t' Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  284 
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'uint32_t' Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  278 
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'uint32_t' Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  296 
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  464 
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  466 
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  468 
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  470 
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  472 
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  479 
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  481 
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  483 
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  485 
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  487 
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  489 
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  491 
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  494 
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  242 
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  248 
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  260 
Error   C3646   'o0': unknown override specifier    Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  479 
Error   C3646   'code': unknown override specifier  Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  464 
Error   C3646   'code': unknown override specifier  Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  466 
Error   C3646   'code': unknown override specifier  Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  468 
Error   C3646   'code': unknown override specifier  Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  470 
Error   C3646   'code': unknown override specifier  Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  472 
Error   C3646   'code': unknown override specifier  Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  477 
Error   C3646   'code': unknown override specifier  Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  479 
Error   C3646   'code': unknown override specifier  Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  481 
Error   C3646   'code': unknown override specifier  Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  483 
Error   C3646   'code': unknown override specifier  Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  485 
Error   C3646   'code': unknown override specifier  Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  487 
Error   C3646   'code': unknown override specifier  Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  489 
Error   C3646   'code': unknown override specifier  Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  491 
Error   C2086   'asmjit::Error asmjit::Assembler::uint32_t': redefinition   Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  466 
Error   C2086   'asmjit::Error asmjit::Assembler::uint32_t': redefinition   Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  468 
Error   C2086   'asmjit::Error asmjit::Assembler::uint32_t': redefinition   Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  470 
Error   C2086   'asmjit::Error asmjit::Assembler::uint32_t': redefinition   Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  472 
Error   C2086   'asmjit::Error asmjit::Assembler::uint32_t': redefinition   Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  477 
Error   C2086   'asmjit::Error asmjit::Assembler::uint32_t': redefinition   Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  479 
Error   C2086   'asmjit::Error asmjit::Assembler::uint32_t': redefinition   Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  481 
Error   C2086   'asmjit::Error asmjit::Assembler::uint32_t': redefinition   Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  483 
Error   C2086   'asmjit::Error asmjit::Assembler::uint32_t': redefinition   Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  485 
Error   C2086   'asmjit::Error asmjit::Assembler::uint32_t': redefinition   Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  487 
Error   C2086   'asmjit::Error asmjit::Assembler::uint32_t': redefinition   Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  489 
Error   C2086   'asmjit::Error asmjit::Assembler::uint32_t': redefinition   Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  491 
Error   C2086   'asmjit::Error asmjit::Assembler::Operand': redefinition    Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  468 
Error   C2086   'asmjit::Error asmjit::Assembler::Operand': redefinition    Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  470 
Error   C2086   'asmjit::Error asmjit::Assembler::Operand': redefinition    Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  481 
Error   C2086   'asmjit::Error asmjit::Assembler::Operand': redefinition    Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  483 
Error   C2086   'asmjit::Error asmjit::Assembler::Operand': redefinition    Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  485 
Error   C2086   'asmjit::Error asmjit::Assembler::Operand': redefinition    Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  487 
Error   C2086   'asmjit::Error asmjit::Assembler::Operand': redefinition    Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  489 
Error   C2086   'asmjit::Error asmjit::Assembler::Operand': redefinition    Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  491 
Error   C2327   'asmjit::Assembler::uint32_t': is not a type name, static, or enumerator    Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  494 
Error   C2327   'asmjit::Assembler::uint32_t': is not a type name, static, or enumerator    Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  513 
Error   C2433   'asmjit::Assembler::uint32_t': '__forceinline' not permitted on data declarations   Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  472 
Error   C2433   'asmjit::Assembler::Operand': '__forceinline' not permitted on data declarations    Loader  C:\Users\Ik\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DC\loader\CustomBone\contrib\AsmJit\base\assembler.h  472
```

Comment: That would be hard to answer just based on the error messages shown. Apparently some types like uint32_t are not defined, which could mean that some basics like <stdint.h> were not included, but since asmjit includes them in its asmjit_build.h it's kinda weird. I would try to first compile asmjit with its tests and report to asmjit issues if they don't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking about this I think the only reason that asmjit doesn't compile with Qt is that qt defines `emit` macro, which collides with asmjit's `emit` function. So after expanding the macro the code:

```
ASMJIT_INLINE Error emit(uint32_t code,
  const Operand& o0,
  const Operand& o1,
  const Operand& o2,
  const Operand& o3) { return _emit(code, o0, o1, o2, o3); }
```

Becomes:

```
ASMJIT_INLINE Error (uint32_t code,
  const Operand& o0,
  const Operand& o1,
  const Operand& o2,
  const Operand& o3) { return _emit(code, o0, o1, o2, o3); }
```

Using Qt with 3rd Party Signals and Slots (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) mentions it:

> `no_keywords` tells Qt not to define the moc keywords signals, slots, and emit, because these names will be used by a 3rd party library, e.g. Boost. Then to continue using Qt signals and slots with the no_keywords flag, simply replace all uses of the Qt moc keywords in your sources with the corresponding Qt macros Q_SIGNALS (or Q_SIGNAL), Q_SLOTS (or Q_SLOT), and Q_EMIT.

Adding `no_keywords` to Qt project is the same as passing `-DQT_NO_KEYWORDS` to the compiler (basically defining `QT_NO_KEYWORDS` to 1).

This could be fixed on asmjit side as well, however, asmjit is doing nothing wrong. You would have the same problem with many other libraries like boost.

Comment: Thanks for your well constructed answer! Good to know its possible to avoid name clashes in Qt with the `QT_NO_KEYWORDS` definition. Will report back soon if this resolves it and mark it as accepted.

Comment: Now if you followed the "good practice" of using the entirely redundant `emit` for Qt signals, you will have to go back and remove all those.